# how to create PDF from report screen data in Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

In my android application i have a report screen where report data are shown in a expandable listview.Now I want to create pdf based on this report screen data.How can i do so.Below picture shows my report screen format.
[image: Report format]

Comment: post your code here

Comment: You should really try to split this into several questions. Have a look at PDF libraries and try to come up with a solution.

Comment: your question is a complex question. You have to solve each task separately. 1. how to create PDF in Android. 2. How to grab data from listview. 3. how to send file by email.

Comment: Ok .I have updated my question.